# Stability of plants and buildings: the role of the xylem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, biophysics, biology

Dicotyledon plants show a stem structure with many xylem tubes, hollow but with lignified (woody) walls. These are arranged as in the figure below, in a circle. Their roots, on the other hand, have the xylem tube positioned in the center of the root body, also in the tap root (the longest, primary root from which all the others branch out.) You can find more information [here](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/mg/Gardennotes/133.html), and the following two figures show the stem and root cross sections, respectively.

**Dicot Stem:**

[image: Dicot Stem]

**Dicot Root:**

[image: Dicot root]

I have heard that this is an adaptation to increase stability, and that indeed having the strongest parts (the woody ones) in the center below ground and in a scattered, regular manner above ground, is the most stable configuration. Also, an horticulture teacher claimed that this has been imitated in the disposition of steel wire and cement typical of very tall buildings.

Is this true? Why and how can it be explained and proved quantitatively?

Comment: More info (physicists are not biologists) http://www.ext.colostate.edu/mg/Gardennotes/133.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to engineering.SE

Comment: While a structural engineer might also have some insight, I feel this has enough physics to be on topic for us. The closure criterion is "does this question not fit here?" not "does this question fit better elsewhere?"

Comment: I am feathering my own nest, but the question is about the physics of the natural system in question, not about the way to engineer, improve or optimise the stability of the system for itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is due to genetic reasons and to provide scope of growth.

The first diagram in which the vascular bundles have been arranged in a ring shape around the center which is made up of soft tissue (Parenchyma-Pith), is actually of a young plant which has not started its secondary growth, so the plant at that time is not that tall, it is young and small and does not need much wood to support it, so the stem is green.

Then, only in gymnosperms and dicots, the interfascicular cambium in between xylem and phloem and interfascicular cambium of the medullary rays, form a cambium ring, Growth begins once more. (Secondary growth)

Xylem is formed on the inner side and crushes the central soft tissue, and a thick central woody. Phloem is formed on the outer side, the outermost region starts producing bark, which breaks due to growth . . .
[image: Secondary growth]

So to answer your question, No, the previous arrangement is just to provide scope for more growth (and its genetic), this new arrangement with central area woody is the most stable configuration (Simplest and strongest). Further, this region of xylem becomes so compact and crushed due to force from new xylem growing, that it stops conducting water, is filled with resins that make it termite resistant and is called heartwood. It is the most expensive type of wood and is the strongest.

[image: Heartwood]
[image: Real heartwood]